# JavaScript detect when IOS browser addres navigation show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two buttons fixed to the bottom of my website. In IOS this has some unwanted behaviour: When the user taps the button, the "bottom browser bar" and "address bar" show up.

Is there a way I can detect if these browserbars are "visible" or "hidden"? So I can adapt the button positions to it?

In the state the bars are visible I added some extra bottom marges so they are on top of the bottom bar. But I want to adjust this when the bars hide.

I tried "onresize" and altough this event fires when the bar show or hide the $(window).height() stays the same. So I can not detect with this method if the screen has become bigger or smaller.

Does anybody know a solution?

[image]

Comment: Not the answer you want to hear, but because of the ~40px "dead area" that blocks clicking elements fixed to the bottom of the screen (and instead brings up the nav bar) we have advised all designers that bottom fixed navigation or functional buttons are forbidden.

Comment: So there is no way to detect if these bars are visible  or not?
How do you fix it when you want a "search" button to be always  visible so the user doesnt have to scroll to the bottom of a "filters-form"?

Comment: I doubt you will be able to determine anything from that event anyway. iOS handles fixed positions poorly in general (just wait till you have a text box w/ focus). I tend to opt for something more like the overflow hidden/auto approach here... http://plnkr.co/edit/Ihl6a3Tq47IBSGOdVsMM I went ahead and moved it to the bottom (which in all fairness I haven't tested on an iOS device but I have the top so it should be the same idea)

Comment: Tried on my iOS simulator and it looks like that approach should work for you.

Answer (score 25):

The `innerHeight` of the page will change depending on whether the top bar is visible. On the iPhone 6 Plus, the `innerHeight` of the page is 628 when the top nav is displayed and 696 when it's not.

You can use the `onresize` function to determine how the `innerHeight` has changed.

Comment: onresize seems to not working now 
 
use resize instead who get issues like me!


window.addEventListener('resize', e => {
 // your codes
});

Comment: may also want to respond to `orientationchange` events as this will also affect the available height.

Comment: @ruucm you can listen to the event via window.onresize or window.addEventListener("resize", ...) - when you use addEventListener, take off the "on" from each event listener function name